# How can I persist invalid edit form data in this Codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-validation

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

There is, among others an "Edit account information" form:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('dashboard/users/update')); ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="uid" value="<?php echo $author->id; ?>">

        <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $author->first_name;?>" placeholder="First name">
          <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo form_error('first_name'); ?> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('last_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $author->last_name;?>" placeholder="Last name">
          <?php if(form_error('last_name')) echo form_error('last_name'); ?> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('email')) echo 'has-error';?>">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $author->email;?>" placeholder="Email">
          <?php if(form_error('email')) echo form_error('email'); ?> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('bio')) echo 'has-error';?>">
          <textarea name="bio" id="bio" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a short bio"><?php echo $author->bio; ?></textarea>
          <?php if(form_error('bio')) echo form_error('bio'); ?> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
        </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

It's corresponding **controller** logic is this:

```
public function edit($id) {
    // Only logged in users can edit user profiles
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['author'] = $this->Usermodel->editAuthor($id);

    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/edit-author');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');

}

public function update() {
    // Only logged in users can edit user profiles
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['author'] = $this->Usermodel->editAuthor($id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/edit-author');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');

    } else
    {
        $this->Usermodel->update_user($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_updated', 'Your account details have been updated');
        redirect(base_url('/dashboard/manage-authors'));
    }
}
```

The problem I have not been able to solve is related to the validation of this form: if I leave a *required filed empty*, and try to submit the form, the form is loaded, with the proper validation error message, only the invalid field is populated with the data from the database and so, valid data is displayed along with the error message, as seen in the form below:

[image]

However, as long as the field's current value is not replaced with an *invalid* one, I want it (the field value) to come from the database.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the submitted data on an input value, you could modify the email codes like this :

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('email')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email', $author->email); ?>" placeholder="Email">
    <?php if(form_error('email')) echo form_error('email'); ?> 
</div>
```

This will set the submitted data as the email value (if available), or email data from the database if there is no submitted email data.

Comment: But, as long as the *email* field is not replaced with an *invalid* one, I want it to come from the database.

Comment: So if user submit an invalid email data, you want to display the data from database (alongside with the error message) and not the invalid submitted data?

Comment: No, I want the invalid submitted data, an empty field, in the case described.

Comment: In that case, I think the codes above should do that